# Azure App Services Linux - NetCore 3 with Kestrel - Modifying max headers size

Tags: azure, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, azure-appservice

I am running a NetCore 3.0 application in Azure App Services with Linux using Kestrel and I have the need to increase the maximum header size.

I am configuring it through code and it works in my local environment, for some reason it's not working when deployed in App Services. Note that I am not using Azure App Gateway or any other service in between so I'm not expecting any restriction on that.

The code I'm using is like this, this allows me to send headers up to 500kb size in my local environment:

```
webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = 1024 * 500;
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50;
});
```

When the app is deployed to App Services the max header size I can pass is around 62kb otherwise I receive a 431 Request Headers Fields Too Large status code.

I am wondering if there is any reverse proxy or any other element that could be intercepting the request before reaching my application and limiting that value. Is there anything else I need to configure so the request can reach my app?

Also at the moment I can't figure out how to find where the request is getting blocked, is there any way I could find out more about this? These kind of requests do not reach my app so I'm not able to log anything, I don't know if there is any log I could check in App Services or related to Kestrel where this requests may be logged.